# Watson Personality Insights api

Tags: ibm-watson, personality-insights

Can I get the personality summary as text using the api like it shows on [personality insights](https://personality-insights-livedemo.mybluemix.net/) demo page. Also how do I get the fields 'You're most likely to...' and 'You're most unlikely to...'. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We have several utility libraries available at https://github.com/personality-insights/, one of which "text-summary" will provide the text summary (given a profile as input). This is the same component we use in the PI demo.

We do not currently provide a way to get the "likely" and "not likely" classifiers, but are looking into a way to provide these.